# Removing commited versions from git history

Tags: git

I want to permanently delete an old revision (or revisions) of single 
file from Git. Specifically, I want to delete from my public git server 
repo my initial published version of one single file, but keep the rest 
of its revisions. How can I do that?

I've done some searching, as follows. But none of them seem to answer my 
specific question. Please help.

Thanks a lot!

git remove oldest revisions of a file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930612/git-remove-oldest-revisions-of-a-file

Completely remove (old) git commits from history
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987341/completely-remove-old-git-commits-from-history

How do you remove a specific revision in the git history?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-revision-in-the-git-history

Answer (score 0):

If the history is simple (linear), a `git rebase -i` should do (the other alternatives will essentially do the same). If you have several branches, you will have to regraft them onto the master branch at the correct points (your "rewrite one early commit" will only afect the branch you modify, others will just retain the original history).

I'd do this (dangerous) experiments on a clone, and replace the original when done and verified correct. Please note that any external clones will get royally confused by the changed history, the only reasonable course of action is to re-clone each.

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand. I found someone else gave a short suggestion of using "git rebase -i", but due to lack of details, I found it only works for un-commented staging changes, and it seems to shorten history of a whole project, rather than a single file.